# Dynamodb batch delete based on sort key pattern

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table with the following structure:

```
sk             |  pk
---------------|-----
1#2023-12-01   |  abv
1#2023-12-02   |  abv
1#2023-12-03   |  abv
1#2023-12-04   |  abv
1#2023-12-05   |  abv
2#2023-12-01   |  abv
2#2023-12-02   |  abv
2#2023-12-03   |  abv
2#2023-12-04   |  abv
2#2023-12-05   |  abv
...
20#2023-12-11  |  abv
20#2023-12-12  |  abv
20#2023-12-12  |  abv
```

Now, I want to perform a batch delete operation on this table where `pk = 'abv'` and `sk` represents a dynamic integer between 1 and 30, followed by a literal `#` and then date part `YYYY-MM-DD` which have to less than the current date(assuming current date is `2023-12-12`). Essentially, I want to remove all items where the date is less than `1-30#2023-12-12`. So after the delete operation on the table, the final table should only contain items like:

```
sk             |  pk
---------------|-----
20#2023-12-12  |  abv
20#2023-12-12  |  abv
```

How can I achieve this in DynamoDB using a batch delete operation? Any guidance on constructing the batch delete request or any other optimized way to code it?. I am thinking this, but I am not a fan of the `scan()` operation of Dynamodb.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Dict, List
class Dynamodb:

    def batch_delete_old_data(self, pk: str):
        try:
            # Calculate the date to keep (e.g., today's date)
            date_to_keep = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

            # Scan for all items with the specified pk
            response = self._table.scan(
                FilterExpression=Key('pk').eq(pk)
            )

            items_to_delete = [{'pk': item['pk'], 'sk': item['sk']} for item in response.get('Items', [])
                               if self.extract_date_part(item['sk']) < date_to_keep]

            with self._table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for item in items_to_delete:
                    batch.delete_item(Key=item)

            return {"message": "Old data cleanup successful"}

        except Exception as e:
            # Handle errors appropriately
            raise Exception(f"Error: {str(e)}")

    @staticmethod
    def extract_date_part(sk: str) -> str:
        # Extract the date part from the sk, assuming format "prefix#date"
        return sk.split('#')[-1] if '#' in sk else sk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you had an item with sort key `20#2023-12-02` would it also maintain to exist after the deletion? If so:
You'll need to execute N Query requests to obtain the items you needs.

If not:
What you are trying to achieve is a range delete, which is not supported in DynamoDB.

To achieve your use-case you must first `Query` to retrieve all of the items where SK `between` X and Y. So instead of `Scan` use `Query` which will be more optimal .

With the results, loop through a `BatchWrite` deleting 25 items per batch. Or as you use batch writer, you can pass the entire result set and it'll chunk into 25 automatically.

Comment: Yes, I don't care about the prefix before `#`, I need to delete everything if the `sk` suffix date is less than my current date. So if `sk` is `20#2023-12-02` and my current date is `2023-12-12`, I need to remove it also. But my concern is- will `Between` works here because it's string not a number or date range value

Comment: Between will work because it's lixicographically ordered. But you'll need to do N query requests for each segment before the prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you give an example how that query will be construct, because on the dynamodb UI I can't do it on my sk right now.

Comment: `Key("sk").between("1#2023-12-01", "1#2023-12-30" )`

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from [Leeroy Hannigan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7909676/leeroy-hannigan), this should work for the conditional range query using the `N` number of `Between` and doing the `batch` delete later. **I am posting this as an answer and I hope it will help others**

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

```
class Dynamodb:

    # ... (existing code)

    def batch_delete_old_data(self, pk_value: str):
        try:
            current_date_iso8601 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  

            start_date_for_between_filter = "2023-12-01"
            dynamic_integer_range = [str(i) for i in range(1, 32)]  # Assuming your range is from 1 to 31

            # Batch delete items
            with self._table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for dynamic_integer in dynamic_integer_range:
                    # Construct a KeyConditionExpression for the query
                    key_condition_expression = (
                        Key('pk').eq(pk_value) &
                        Key('sk').between(f"{dynamic_integer}#{start_date_for_between_filter}", f"{dynamic_integer}#{current_date_iso8601}")
                    )

                    # Perform the query with the constructed KeyConditionExpression
                    response = self._table.query(
                        KeyConditionExpression=key_condition_expression
                    )

                    # Prepare items for batch delete
                    items_to_delete = [{'pk': item['pk'], 'sk': item['sk']} for item in response.get('Items', [])]

                    # Batch delete items
                    for item in items_to_delete:
                        batch.delete_item(Key=item)

            return {"message": "Old data cleanup successful"}

        except Exception as e:
            # Handle errors appropriately
            raise Exception(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```